# Finding poles of a function in a region of the complex plane matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a symbolic function f and I'm trying to find the poles of f in a given region of the complex plane.

I suppose the pole() function would be useful: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/poles.html

However there is no option to search for poles of f only in a given region. I know my function has an infinite number of poles in the complex plane and so the function always returns empty. Is there a way to restrict it to look for poles in a certain region?

Thanks for any help

Comment: As you found out, the poles command cannot do this. Perhaps your function has some structure that can be exploited here, e.g., isolate denominator and try to find its zeros using the solve command.